# Does AWS GP3 SSD volume default to baseline value for IOPS and throughput fields if they are not specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Based on AWS documentation, GP3 SSD delivers a baseline performance of:

1. 3,000 IOPS (scalable up to 16,000 iops)
2. 125 MB/s throughput (scalable up to 1,000 MB/s)

I am working on creating a Kubernetes `StorageClass` resource for provisioning the AWS GP3 SSD volume. I am thinking whether EBS will perform defaulting to the fields so that I do not need to specify the fields under `.parameters` field of the `StorageClass` resource.

For example:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp3
  iops: 3000 // Will EBS default this to baseline value so that this can be skipped?
  throughput: 125 // Same here.
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Comment: Throughput can not be set on any EBS volume and iops can only be set on io1 and io2 types.

Comment: Why do you use the `throughput` and `iops` parameters (they seem to be unavailable for this storage class) ?
For information about the options available for AWS storage classes, see [AWS EBS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs) in the Kubernetes documentation.